# Incremental Addition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not sure why I have become so puzzled by this, but I am pretty sure I am completely overcomplicating everything here.

The equation (or set of equations) I am trying to make has a starting price, ending price, multiplier, and a quantity. I am trying to get the ending price only.

So if I give it a price of 40, a quantity of 4 and a multiplier of 0.0001 it would return an ending price of 40.0006

(40 + 40.0001 + 40.0002 + 40.0003) = 160.0006

It starts at 40 because that is my price, it does it 4 times because that is my quantity, and it goes up 0.0001 each time because that is my multiplier.

I have tried summation formulas, but it never seems to end up right

Comment: You wrote "(40 + 40.0001 + 40.0002 + 40.0003) = 40.0006" which is incorrect. The correct sum is 160.0006. Can you clarify this part?

Comment: Sorry I was focusing too much on what happens with the decimal that I completely ignored the integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\underbrace{start + (start + mult) + (start + 2\cdot mult) + ..... +(start + \{quant-1\}\cdot mult)}_{quant \text{ times}}=$

$\underbrace{start + start + .... + start}_{quant\text{ times}} + mult(0+ 1+2+3+...... +\{quant-1\}) =$

$quant\cdot start + mult\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{quant-1} k$

....

Now there is a well known trick that everyone remembers where they where when they first learned it[1] (and everyone is secretly envious of the kid who aged less than ten years old who figured it on his own in a matter of a half a minute) that

$1 + 2 + 3+ ..... +n = \frac {n(n+1)}2$.

So:  You want:

$quant\cdot start + mult\cdot \frac {(quant -1)\cdot quant}2$

.....

[1] It's the mathematician's equivalence of JFK....

JFK?... He was a president of the United States a while back?....  Apparently he died and it was big deal for the people at the time... I dunno, I don't remember him either.